# Retorna el parámetro de entrada y no los datos de sp

Tags: webservice, asp.net-core, stored-procedure, postman

realicé un servicio donde tiene un parámetro de entrada que es cod_liquidacion , pero al ingresar en mi método no me retorna el resultado del procedure que estoy utilizando , sino que me regresa el valor ingresado en mi parámetro y esta mal , tiene que regresarme la respuesta del store Procedure , ¿qué error estoy cometiendo? en donde debo corregir el código para que me retorne el procedure que estoy utilizando

este es mi servicio

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Salesws.Context;
using Salesws.Models;
using Salesws.Service;
using Salesws.Service.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace Salesws.RestControllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class LoginController : ControllerBase
    {

        private IConfiguration _config;
        //Contexto de la base de datos SVM
        private readonly SVMcontext _context;
        private readonly ILambSelLiquidacionService _iamb_Sel_Liquidacion;
        public LoginController(IConfiguration config, SVMcontext context,IFechaService fechaService,ILambSelLiquidacionService amb_Sel_LiquidacionService)
        {
            _config = config;
            _context = context;
            _iamb_Sel_Liquidacion = amb_Sel_LiquidacionService;
        }

        [HttpGet("ugv_getDSCargaDroidRepartidor/{cod_liquidacion}")]
        public ActionResult ugv_getDSCargaDroidRepartidor( int cod_liquidacion)
        {
            var rpta = _iamb_Sel_Liquidacion.liquidacion(cod_liquidacion);
            return Ok(rpta);
        }

    }
}
```

este es mi Interfaceservicio

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Salesws.Service.Interfaces
{
    public interface ILambSelLiquidacionService
    {
        public string liquidacion(int cod_liquidacion);
    }
}
```

este es mi service

```
using Salesws.Service.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Salesws.Service
{
    public class AmbSelLiquidacionService : ILambSelLiquidacionService
    {
        private ILambSelLiquidacionRepository _liqui;
        public AmbSelLiquidacionService(ILambSelLiquidacionRepository liqui)
        {
            _liqui = liqui;
        }

        public string liquidacion(int cod_liquidacion)
        {
            return _liqui.liquidacion(cod_liquidacion);
        }
    }
}
```

este es mi interfaceRepository

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Salesws.Service.Interfaces
{
    public interface ILambSelLiquidacionRepository
    {
        public string liquidacion(int cod_liquidacion);
    }
}
```

este es mi repository

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Salesws.Context;
using Salesws.Service.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Salesws.Models
{
    public class AmbSelLiquidacionRepository : ILambSelLiquidacionRepository
    {
        private readonly SVMcontext _context;


        public AmbSelLiquidacionRepository(SVMcontext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public string liquidacion(int cod_liquidacion)
        {
            string liqui = "";
            using (DbCommand command = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "dbo.amb_sel_liquidacion";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@p_cod_liquidacion", cod_liquidacion);
                command.Parameters.Add(param);
                
                _context.Database.OpenConnection();
                using (var resultado = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (resultado.Read())
                    {
                        liqui = resultado[0].ToString();
                    }
                }
                _context.Database.CloseConnection();
            }
            return liqui;
        }

        
    }
}
```

este es el resultado , y no me regresa el resultado del procedure  , sino la valor ingresada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No he trabajado con core lo suficiente para dar una respuesta, pero por lo que veo el problema podría estar en el Store Procedure. ¿tienes acceso a la base de datos (Sql Server, Posgres...) para ejecutar el SP `dbo.amb_sel_liquidacion` de forma manual? la idea es que verifiques _cual_ y _cuantos_ valores retorna el SP: tu código actual devuelve el _primer campo_ de la _última fila_ del resultado (!)

Comment: @Roimer si , tiene los permisos y devuelve varios datos

Comment: OK, aunque me refería a que tú te loguees directamente en la base de datos (usando SQL Server Management Studio, phpMyAdmin, o lo que corresponda a tu base de datos), para que vieras la respuesta directamente en el origen.

Comment: si , probé el sp desde sqlserver y funciona bien , pero en mi vb me da como resultado el dato ingresado